# Preciso exibir todas a vendas do dia MVC C#

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Através de um input o usuário insere a data e assim list todos os produtos respectivo daquele dia

```
    public void Buscar(Lancamento lancamento)
    {
        string sql = string.Format("SELECT DataHora FROM Lancamento",lancamento.DataHora);
        ExecuteCommand(sql);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Buscar(DateTime DataHora)
    {
        return View("IndexLancamento");
    }

    <form action="@Url.Action("Buscar", "Lancamento")" method="post">
        <input type="text" value="@Model.Buscar" placeholder="Buscar por Data" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Buscar</button>
    </form>
   <table>
        <tr>
           <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
       @{foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.DataHora</td>
            </tr>
        }        
        }
  </table>
```

Comment: E qual é a sua dúvida? onde está a `Action` passando a `ViewModel` para a view?

Comment: Preciso listar os produtos por data.
Não estou sabendo fazer a conexão passando este comando(ViewModel).

Answer (score 0):

Seu método que busca os lançamentos do banco deve retornar uma lista de todos os lançamentos daquele dia, e não void como está sendo feito.

Feito isso, é só retornar a View e passando como argumento o que foi retornado.